# Search an object from nested n level array / JSON object in java script

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, traversal

I have a JSON object with a nested list. Each element from this list can also be a nested list. The depth of each element can go up to n-levels. I need to iterate over all the elements and get the object matching the search criteria. Let's say the item name. 
If I search for an item name that corresponding object should be returned.

List structure

[image]

Nested structure

[image]

Below is the sample JSON structure.

```js
{
  "Description": "Rooftop heating/ cooling",
  "Category": "HVAC",
  "PartNumber": "MTU987456",
  "Quantity": "1",
  "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
  "BomID": "BOM-430",
  "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
  "GroupID": "BOM-430",
  "pxObjClass": "",
  "Custom3": "cust3 data",
  "Type": "Configured product",
  "Custom2": "cust2 data",
  "Uom": "each",
  "Custom1": "cust1 data",
  "ReferenceId": "1552780013",
  "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
  "BOMLevel": "0",
  "ItemName": "3-6-9 ton Rooftop heating/ cooling",
  "Supplier": "Voltas",
  "PartRevision": "MTU987456",
  "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Unit casing",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U987456",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-431",
      "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust3 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust2 data",
      "Uom": "each",
      "Custom1": "cust1 data",
      "ReferenceId": "15527456",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Unit casing",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U987456",
      "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
          "ParentID": "BOM-431",
          "Description": "Metal casing",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "M987456",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-432",
          "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust3 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust2 data",
          "Uom": "each",
          "Custom1": "cust1 data",
          "ReferenceId": "1M5527456",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Metal casing",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "M987456",
          "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
            "ParentID": "BOM-432",
            "Description": "Fibre casing insulation",
            "Category": "HVAC",
            "PartNumber": "M98745e",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
            "BomID": "BOM-433",
            "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
            "GroupID": "BOM-430",
            "pxObjClass": "",
            "Custom3": "cust3 data",
            "Type": "Part",
            "Custom2": "cust2 data",
            "Uom": "each",
            "Custom1": "cust1 data",
            "ReferenceId": "1M5C527456",
            "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
            "BOMLevel": "3",
            "ItemName": "Fibre casing insulation",
            "Supplier": "Voltas",
            "PartRevision": "M98745e",
            "pxUniqueElementID": 1
          }],
          "pxUniqueElementID": 1
        },
        {
          "ParentID": "BOM-431",
          "Description": "Fibre casing",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "M98745e",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-445",
          "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust3 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust2 data",
          "Uom": "each",
          "Custom1": "cust1 data",
          "ReferenceId": "1M5527457",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Fibre casing",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "M98745e",
          "pxUniqueElementID": 2
        }
      ],
      "pxUniqueElementID": 1
    },
    {
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Evaporator coil",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U774488",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "21(h)X21(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-434",
      "Sublocation": "2nd Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust6 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust5 data",
      "Uom": "one",
      "Custom1": "cust4 data",
      "ReferenceId": "205456",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Evaporator coil",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U774488",
      "pxUniqueElementID": 2
    },
    {
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Fan assembly",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U1FN41100",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-435",
      "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust9 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust8 data",
      "Uom": "one",
      "Custom1": "cust7 data",
      "ReferenceId": "205457",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Fan assembly",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U1FN41100",
      "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
          "ParentID": "BOM-435",
          "Description": "Motor",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "U14110MOT0",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-436",
          "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust9 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust8 data",
          "Uom": "one",
          "Custom1": "cust7 data",
          "ReferenceId": "20MO5457",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Motor",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "U14110MOT0",
          "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
            "ParentID": "BOM-436",
            "Description": "Rotor",
            "Category": "HVAC",
            "PartNumber": "U1RR41100",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
            "BomID": "BOM-437",
            "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
            "GroupID": "BOM-430",
            "pxObjClass": "",
            "Custom3": "cust9 data",
            "Type": "Part",
            "Custom2": "cust8 data",
            "Uom": "one",
            "Custom1": "cust7 data",
            "ReferenceId": "20MORO5457",
            "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
            "BOMLevel": "3",
            "ItemName": "Rotor",
            "Supplier": "Voltas",
            "PartRevision": "U1RR41100",
            "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
              "ParentID": "BOM-437",
              "Description": "Steel bearings",
              "Category": "HVAC",
              "PartNumber": "U1411ST00",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
              "BomID": "BOM-438",
              "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
              "GroupID": "BOM-430",
              "pxObjClass": "",
              "Custom3": "cust9 data",
              "Type": "Part",
              "Custom2": "cust8 data",
              "Uom": "one",
              "Custom1": "cust7 data",
              "ReferenceId": "20MOBEO5457",
              "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
              "BOMLevel": "3",
              "ItemName": "Steel bearings",
              "Supplier": "Voltas",
              "PartRevision": "U1411ST00",
              "pxUniqueElementID": 1
            }],
            "pxUniqueElementID": 1
          }],
          "pxUniqueElementID": 1
        },
        {
          "ParentID": "BOM-435",
          "Description": "Propeller fan",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "U141100",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-439",
          "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust9 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust8 data",
          "Uom": "one",
          "Custom1": "cust7 data",
          "ReferenceId": "205GO457",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Propeller fan",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "PR3",
          "pxUniqueElementID": 2
        }
      ],
      "pxUniqueElementID": 3
    },
    {
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Compressor",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U78999",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "23(h)X23(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-440",
      "Sublocation": "4th Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust12 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust11 data",
      "Uom": "each",
      "Custom1": "cust10 data",
      "ReferenceId": "205458",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Compressor",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U78999",
      "pxUniqueElementID": 4
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: please use a smaller data set and add this data to the question with what you have and what you want. please to add your try, too.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function searchItemByName(sourceObject, name) {

    if (sourceObject['ItemName'] === name) {
        return sourceObject;
    }

    if (sourceObject['ChildrenBillOfMaterials']) {
        for (let i = 0; i < sourceObject['ChildrenBillOfMaterials'].length; i++) {
            let targetObject = searchItemByName(sourceObject['ChildrenBillOfMaterials'][i], name)
            if (targetObject !== null) {
                return targetObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are my hero. I was struggling with recursion in a similar matter, this made it soooo clear. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple syntax error like logs said

It is no correct in js to start line with { ... } .

Your JSON object is valid but need assigns to the object instance.
In other word you need to use :

> var someObject = { ... }

```js
try {

var test = {
  "Description": "Rooftop heating/ cooling",
  "Category": "HVAC",
  "PartNumber": "MTU987456",
  "Quantity": "1",
  "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
  "BomID": "BOM-430",
  "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
  "GroupID": "BOM-430",
  "pxObjClass": "",
  "Custom3": "cust3 data",
  "Type": "Configured product",
  "Custom2": "cust2 data",
  "Uom": "each",
  "Custom1": "cust1 data",
  "ReferenceId": "1552780013",
  "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
  "BOMLevel": "0",
  "ItemName": "3-6-9 ton Rooftop heating/ cooling",
  "Supplier": "Voltas",
  "PartRevision": "MTU987456",
  "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Unit casing",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U987456",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-431",
      "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust3 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust2 data",
      "Uom": "each",
      "Custom1": "cust1 data",
      "ReferenceId": "15527456",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Unit casing",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U987456",
      "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
          "ParentID": "BOM-431",
          "Description": "Metal casing",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "M987456",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-432",
          "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust3 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust2 data",
          "Uom": "each",
          "Custom1": "cust1 data",
          "ReferenceId": "1M5527456",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Metal casing",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "M987456",
          "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
            "ParentID": "BOM-432",
            "Description": "Fibre casing insulation",
            "Category": "HVAC",
            "PartNumber": "M98745e",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
            "BomID": "BOM-433",
            "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
            "GroupID": "BOM-430",
            "pxObjClass": "",
            "Custom3": "cust3 data",
            "Type": "Part",
            "Custom2": "cust2 data",
            "Uom": "each",
            "Custom1": "cust1 data",
            "ReferenceId": "1M5C527456",
            "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
            "BOMLevel": "3",
            "ItemName": "Fibre casing insulation",
            "Supplier": "Voltas",
            "PartRevision": "M98745e",
            "pxUniqueElementID": 1
          }],
          "pxUniqueElementID": 1
        },
        {
          "ParentID": "BOM-431",
          "Description": "Fibre casing",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "M98745e",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "20(h)X20(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-445",
          "Sublocation": "1st Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust3 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust2 data",
          "Uom": "each",
          "Custom1": "cust1 data",
          "ReferenceId": "1M5527457",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Fibre casing",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "M98745e",
          "pxUniqueElementID": 2
        }
      ],
      "pxUniqueElementID": 1
    },
    {
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Evaporator coil",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U774488",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "21(h)X21(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-434",
      "Sublocation": "2nd Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust6 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust5 data",
      "Uom": "one",
      "Custom1": "cust4 data",
      "ReferenceId": "205456",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Evaporator coil",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U774488",
      "pxUniqueElementID": 2
    },
    {
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Fan assembly",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U1FN41100",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-435",
      "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust9 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust8 data",
      "Uom": "one",
      "Custom1": "cust7 data",
      "ReferenceId": "205457",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Fan assembly",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U1FN41100",
      "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
          "ParentID": "BOM-435",
          "Description": "Motor",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "U14110MOT0",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-436",
          "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust9 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust8 data",
          "Uom": "one",
          "Custom1": "cust7 data",
          "ReferenceId": "20MO5457",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Motor",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "U14110MOT0",
          "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
            "ParentID": "BOM-436",
            "Description": "Rotor",
            "Category": "HVAC",
            "PartNumber": "U1RR41100",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
            "BomID": "BOM-437",
            "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
            "GroupID": "BOM-430",
            "pxObjClass": "",
            "Custom3": "cust9 data",
            "Type": "Part",
            "Custom2": "cust8 data",
            "Uom": "one",
            "Custom1": "cust7 data",
            "ReferenceId": "20MORO5457",
            "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
            "BOMLevel": "3",
            "ItemName": "Rotor",
            "Supplier": "Voltas",
            "PartRevision": "U1RR41100",
            "ChildrenBillOfMaterials": [{
              "ParentID": "BOM-437",
              "Description": "Steel bearings",
              "Category": "HVAC",
              "PartNumber": "U1411ST00",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
              "BomID": "BOM-438",
              "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
              "GroupID": "BOM-430",
              "pxObjClass": "",
              "Custom3": "cust9 data",
              "Type": "Part",
              "Custom2": "cust8 data",
              "Uom": "one",
              "Custom1": "cust7 data",
              "ReferenceId": "20MOBEO5457",
              "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
              "BOMLevel": "3",
              "ItemName": "Steel bearings",
              "Supplier": "Voltas",
              "PartRevision": "U1411ST00",
              "pxUniqueElementID": 1
            }],
            "pxUniqueElementID": 1
          }],
          "pxUniqueElementID": 1
        },
        {
          "ParentID": "BOM-435",
          "Description": "Propeller fan",
          "Category": "HVAC",
          "PartNumber": "U141100",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "Dimensions": "22(h)X22(b)",
          "BomID": "BOM-439",
          "Sublocation": "3rd Floor",
          "GroupID": "BOM-430",
          "pxObjClass": "",
          "Custom3": "cust9 data",
          "Type": "Part",
          "Custom2": "cust8 data",
          "Uom": "one",
          "Custom1": "cust7 data",
          "ReferenceId": "205GO457",
          "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
          "BOMLevel": "2",
          "ItemName": "Propeller fan",
          "Supplier": "Voltas",
          "PartRevision": "PR3",
          "pxUniqueElementID": 2
        }
      ],
      "pxUniqueElementID": 3
    },
    {
      "ParentID": "BOM-430",
      "Description": "Compressor",
      "Category": "HVAC",
      "PartNumber": "U78999",
      "Quantity": "1",
      "Dimensions": "23(h)X23(b)",
      "BomID": "BOM-440",
      "Sublocation": "4th Floor",
      "GroupID": "BOM-430",
      "pxObjClass": "",
      "Custom3": "cust12 data",
      "Type": "Part",
      "Custom2": "cust11 data",
      "Uom": "each",
      "Custom1": "cust10 data",
      "ReferenceId": "205458",
      "Manufacturer": "AirXpert Systems",
      "BOMLevel": "1",
      "ItemName": "Compressor",
      "Supplier": "Voltas",
      "PartRevision": "U78999",
      "pxUniqueElementID": 4
    }

  ]
};
console.log(test)
} catch(err){console.log(err)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can continue finding child element using "."

```
 $.each("jsonobj variable", function(index, element) {
   alert(element.description); 
  });
```